# "The President was/is to address the gathering."

Tags: tense, infinitives

What is the difference between the following sentences

1. The President ***was to*** address the gathering.
2. The President ***is to*** address the gathering.

Comment: Do you understand the temporal difference between **was** and **is**? Do you understand what those sentences mean individually?

Comment: Try to understand something; when you say or see this sentence: "The President was to address the gathering," YOU are in the present looking back at that past. The past tense "was" means "an action that started and ended before now" of which YOU are in. The now. That's all the sentence means. The President was scheduled to address the gathering at some specific time in the past. Did he? Who cares. If not, will he? Again, who cares. Don't put into a sentence what it does not mean. However, this construction is often used when someone, like the President, didn't address the gathering.

Comment: Usually you'll hear this on the News, and after it is said, the newsman or newswomen (I wouldn't want to upset anyone) will go on to tell what happened and why the President didn't speak. The other sentence uses the present tense "is" which is used to state facts. It is a fact that the President is scheduled to address the crowd. That's all. Nothing more. Again, YOU are in the now, and are waiting for the President to speak to the crowd. It could be at any time AFTER you heard, read, the sentence.

Answer (score 2):

*X am/is/was/were to Y* means that a plan has been made for X to do Y.  It is also used by an authority figure or leader to A) indirectly tell someone what to do, B) tell someone else what they should be doing, or C) tell someone else that someone else is doing something instead.

*Is to* is a present tense of this, and *was to* is a past tense of this.

> The President was to address the gathering.

There was a plan, in the past, for the President to address the gathering.  (We don't know if he actually did or anything more than that he was supposed to do the addressing.)

> The President is to address the gathering.

There is a plan, now, for the President to address the gathering. (This may have been said if someone else thought they were going to address the gathering, to make it clear that it's the President that's going to be doing that.)

Comment: But can we not use #1 to refer to future and not past: Like in a) We don't know if the President is going to address the gathering in the future, but from the point of view of the past, when I was sure or when I heard that he would, I could say this, but I am not sure now, so I don't use 'he is to'. b)When president has cancelled his address and is no longer going to address it, then I can say, 'the president was to address the gathering'. Can I use the above situations with #1?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you can.  You have the right idea.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Advanced Grammar in Use by Martin Hewings.Unit 14;page 28

Comment: Hello, welcome to ELL! While this may answer the question, a full page screenshot is really difficult to read and it is not immediately obvious how the information in your screenshot answers the question *directly*. Instead of posting screenshots, could you summarize the information and give a straightforward answer to the question?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer couldn't be any more straightforward than this one no matter however I try to explain it in my own way.However let me have a try.Construction with was/were to + bare infinite means the action was performed unless it is followed by an explanation why it was not as in (1)'He was to take her out for dinner but was called back to his office to attend to some urgent matters(=the meeting did not take place).If you say 'He was to take her out for dinner',it means it took place,and if you say 'He was to have taken her out for dinner',it means the event didn't take place as in (1)

Comment: I could copy-paste the text on the screenshot but it is copy-right material